# Error _create while rendering belongsTo children in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to render `mediaitems` in my `post` template, but I'm getting this nasty console error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object photo has no method '_create'`

These are my models & fixture data:

```
/**************************
 * Models
 **************************/

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});



App.Mediaitem = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),

    post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});



App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    summary: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),

    mediaitems: DS.hasMany('App.Mediaitem', {embedded:true})
});

App.Post.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id:"post-one", 
        type:"news", 
        title:"First Post", 
        summary:"Ipsum Lorem", 
        date:"2013-02-07T16:44:57",
        mediaitems:[{
            id:593,
            post_id:"post-one",
            type:'photo',
            url:'http://www.google.com'
        },
        {
            id:789,
            post_id:"post-one",
            type:'photo',
            url:'http://www.google.com'
        }]
    }, 
    {
        id:"post-two",
        type:"gallery", 
        title:"Second Post", 
        summary:"Lorem ipsum", 
        date:"2013-02-07T16:44:57",
        mediaitems:[{
            id:342,
            post_id:"post-two",
            type:'photo',
            url:'http://www.google.com'
        },
        {
            id:231,
            post_id:"post-two",
            type:'photo',
            url:'http://www.google.com'
        }]
    }
];
```

This is my template code:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
        <div class="detail">
            {{#linkTo posts}}close{{/linkTo}}<br/>
            <h2>{{id}} - {{title}}</h2>
            <br/>
            {{#each mediaitem in mediaitems}}
                print something
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIXTURE adapter does not support embedded relationships, at least not in rev 11.
You need each model to have its own FIXTURE definition with the record and the relationships to have the id/s of the proper child/parent.

```
App.Post.FIXTURES = [
{
    id:"post-one", 
    type:"news", 
    title:"First Post", 
    summary:"Ipsum Lorem", 
    date:"2013-02-07T16:44:57",
    mediaitems:['593','789']
}, 
{
    id:"post-two",
    type:"gallery", 
    title:"Second Post", 
    summary:"Lorem ipsum", 
    date:"2013-02-07T16:44:57",
    mediaitems:['342','231']
}];

App.Mediaitems.FIXTURES = [{
        id:342,
        post_id:"post-two",
        type:'photo',
        url:'http://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        id:231,
        post_id:"post-two",
        type:'photo',
        url:'http://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        id:593,
        post_id:"post-one",
        type:'photo',
        url:'http://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        id:789,
        post_id:"post-one",
        type:'photo',
        url:'http://www.google.com'
    }];
```